# Convert DetailView to APIView in Django

Tags: django, api, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views

I am converting **Django to Django REST API**. Now I am facing error with **self.object** in APIView. How can I use **self.object** or substitute option in APIView?

**Here is my DetailView...**

```
class ChapterDetail(DetailView):
    model= Chapter
    context_object_name = 'chapter'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(ChapterDetail, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        user = self.request.user
        user_practice_game = UserPracticeGame.objects.filter(user=user).filter(practice_game__chapter=self.object).first()
   
        context['user_practice_game'] = user_practice_game

        return context
```

**Here is my APIView...**

```
class ChapterDetailAPIView(APIView): # need review
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        context = {}
        qs_user_practice_game = UserPracticeGame.objects.filter(user=self.request.user).filter(practice_game__chapter=
        upg_serializer = UserPracticeGame(qs_user_practice_game, many=True)
        context['user_practice_game'] = upg_serializer.data
        return Response(context, status=200)
```

In APIView, I can't use **practice_game__chapter=self.object** in the query!

**This is my model...**

```
class UserPracticeGame(DateMixin, models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name='User', related_name='user_practice_game')
    practice_game = models.ForeignKey(PracticeGame, on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name='Practice Game', related_name='user_practice_game')
    total_answered = models.IntegerField(verbose_name='Total Answered', default=0, blank=True, null=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

`DetailView` provides a member method called `get_object()` which is responsible for providing the corresponding object( object that we get from `self.object`).

Use `GenericAPIView` from drf instead of `APIView`. It provides the same `get_object()` method and thus you can get access to the object. This should resolve your problem.

```
class ChapterDetailAPIView(GenericAPIView):
    queryset = Chapter.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ChapterSerializer # you need a serializer for Chapter
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        context = {}
        curr_obj = self.get_object()
        qs_user_practice_game = UserPracticeGame.objects.filter(user=self.request.user).filter(practice_game__chapter=curr_obj)
        upg_serializer = UserPracticeGame(qs_user_practice_game, many=True)
        context['user_practice_game'] = upg_serializer.data
        return Response(context, status=200)
```

for more information on `GenericAPIView` follow drf [documentation](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/generic-views/#genericapiview).

Comment: hello @mursalin, after trying your way, now I'm facing..."AssertionError: 'ChapterDetailAPIView' should either include a queryset attribute, or override the get_queryset() method." So, what I should do to overcome this? Thanks for your help.

Comment: @MinhajulIslam, I have updated the answer. ```GenericAPIView``` are for more of a generic purpose, so you have to add some attribute to it, you can also check ```RetriveAPIView```. Dont expect the answer to work as is, the answer is there to direct you to right direction. please check the documentation link I provided.